# query about application T-SQL joins

Tags: sql

We have a table with the following structure -
Table(id, key_type, key_value) where (id, key_type) is the primary key.

Due to some bug in the softwares writing to this table, there can be cases where you have same  combinations of (key_type,key_value) but with different ids.

We want to find out all such incorrect data, where all the combinations of (key_type,key_value) are same even though id can be different.

Interestingly, the number of such combinations will vary i.e. they are not same across all the ids.

for example,

if the rows are -

1. (1, type1, value1)
2. (1, type2, value2)
3. (2, type1, value1)
4. (2, type2, value2)
5. (3, type3, value3)
6. (4, type4, value4)
7. (5, type3, value3)
8. (6, type1, value1)
9. (6, type3, value3)

The query should flag off ids (1 & 2) and (3 & 5)
Maybe the solution is trivial but I would blame it to my little experience with SQL.
Can someone please help me out here, Thanks!

Comment: Your calculation of the ids that should be flagged is incorrect, or you have stated the problem incorrectly. Row 4 duplicates row 2, Row 7 duplicates row 5/9, Row 8 duplicates rows 1/3 and row 9 duplicates Row 7/5. Why do you not expect rows 4,7,8,9 to be flagged?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), key_type, key_value
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY key_type, key_value
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That will give you key types and values where you have duplicates or triplicates etc

If you then want the ID's as well, you can subquery it can get the rows where they exist withing the set of duplicates

```
SELECT ID,  key_type, key_value
FROM YourTable y
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT count(*), key_type, key_value
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY key_type, key_value
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) dup ON y.key_value = dup.key_value and y.key_type = dup.key_type
```

Comment: I want to find out the ids where all the combinations of (key_type, key_value) are same but this query will return me all the ids which even have just one combination same.

Comment: Double check that, the having clause specifically requires the coune to be above 1, e.g. duplicates.

Comment: For the given rows in the post, the query is returning me - 1,2,3,5,6. If you see (1,2) and 6 have one row(key_type and key_value) different. The query still returns 6. I need to return the ids which have all the combinations repeating. Thanks!

Comment: Run the inner select and check the results of that, if it returns a row, then it considers the count to be greater than 1, indicating a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct id 
from T1 t
inner join (
    SELECT key_type, key_value 
    FROM T1 
    GROUP BY key_type, key_value 
    HAVING count(distinct id) > 1 
) td on t.key_type = td.key_type and t.key_value = td.key_value
```

**Output:**

```
id
-----------
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: For the given rows in the post, the query is returning me - 1,2,3,5,6. If you see (1,2) and 6 have one row(key_type and key_value) different. The query still returns 6. I need to return the ids which have all the combinations repeating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you where your bug is, and that is in the Primary keys. You have an autonumber (id) combined with key_type. This will always allow duplicate values of key_type/key_value since id will always be unique and is part of the key.

By making key_type and key_value the primary keys and dropping the id, you'll save yourself the pain going forward on this. Otherwise, make id the only primary key